# how can I get the text around whatsapp fa icon?

Tags: css

I'm trying to put the svg text around the whatsapp fa icon, something like this

[image]

but unable to achieve desired result. this is what I'm getting so far.

[image]

I tried with the below code.

```
<a id='whatsapp' 
  style={{
    bottom: '162px', right: '32px', fontSize: '3.3rem', 
    padding: '0.6rem', backgroundColor: '#70d470', 
    color: '#fff'        
    }} 
    href="https://wa.me/1232365326" 
    target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" 
    className={`${visible ? "block whatsapp" : "none"}`}
>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
      <defs>
        <path id="circle"
          d="
            M 50, 50
            m -37, 0
            a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
            a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
      </defs>
      <text font-size="8">
        <textPath xlinkHref="#circle">
          Need Appointment? Click me!
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
  <RiWhatsappFill/>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using `position: 'absolute'` on the text, then aligning it manually.

Here's something that might work, give it a shot.

```
<a id='whatsapp' 
  style={{
    bottom: '162px', right: '32px', fontSize: '3.3rem', 
    padding: '0.6rem', backgroundColor: '#70d470', 
    color: '#fff'        
    }} 
    href="https://wa.me/1232365326" 
    target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" 
    className={`${visible ? "block whatsapp" : "none"}`}
>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
      <defs>
        <path id="circle"
          d="
            M 50, 50
            m -37, 0
            a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
            a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
      </defs>
      <text style={{position: 'absolute', right: '32px', top: '2px'}}  font-size="8">
        <textPath xlinkHref="#circle">
          Need Appointment? Click me!
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
  <RiWhatsappFill/>
</a>
```